how to read file inside src folder in java function app
how can I access a file inside src->main->java->resource->filename.txt. it should work both in local and deployed version.
File privateFile=new File("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\test\\java-test-function-app\\src\\main\\java\\resource\\test.txt");

I want to use relative path instead of a complete path.

If you want to use relative path and you has used SpringBoot,you should do:
URL resource=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
File file = new File(resource.getPath());

